# Java sample login - missing return

Tags: java, arraylist, authentication

I am still new to this can you please help me on the below as I am getting "missing return statement" error.

```
public static Person login(ArrayList<Person> per, String password, int idint)
    {
        for (Person currentPerson : per)
               {
                        if (idint == currentPerson.Id)
                        {
                        if (currentPerson.password.equals(password)){
                            System.out.println("Login Succesfully!");
                            return currentPerson;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {System.out.println("Incorrect password. Try again");
                            return null;
                        }} 
                    else {
                        System.out.println("User not found. Try again");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

    }
```

where per is my Person arraylist. I need to return the person when found.

Comment: you must have a return statement at the end of the method. so `return null;` So right above that last bracket.

Comment: but returning null will end up with always returning null?

Comment: oh So return something ? idk. I'm just telling you where to put it

Comment: The metod needs to return something if null is not correct change your code so that you return the correct Person, note: it is not strange to return null but pretty common, in your case it could be no one logged in, login faliure

Comment: be carefull of your if else  statment you will never loop them all.. when you do return you exit loop...

Comment: System.out.println("User not found. Try again"); return null; take them out of the loop and put them under...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two more cases to be considered.

1. `per` list  empty or null.
2. `idint` not present in the list.

You can cover those two cases just adding only two statement, as other answers said.

```
public static Person login(ArrayList<Person> per, String password, int idint) {
        //null list or empty list
        if(per == null || per.size() == 0)
            return null;
        for (Person currentPerson : per) {
            if (idint == currentPerson.Id) {
                if (currentPerson.password.equals(password)) {
                    System.out.println("Login Succesfully!");
                    return currentPerson;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect password. Try again");
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("User not found. Try again");
                return null;
            }
        }
        //Person is not present in the list
        return null;

    }
```

You should consider using `HashMap` instead of an `ArrayList` to keep the `Person` objects, it will guarantee there is no duplicate `Person` object for the same `Person` and enables instant time access to the `Person` object with given id.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is giving you error since `currentPerson` can be empty, hence you never enter loop.

But, you are really close  you only need to move the

```
System.out.println("User not found. Try again");
return null;
```

out of the loop,

now you are exiting the loop on first `Person` `if idint == currentPerson.Id`, you check password and then exit else you exit... you never loop them all.

```
        for (Person currentPerson : per)
           {
                 if (idint == currentPerson.Id)
                 {
                    if (currentPerson.password.equals(password)){
                        System.out.println("Login Succesfully!");
                        return currentPerson;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                       System.out.println("Incorrect password. Try again");
                        return null;
                    }
                } 

            }

           System.out.println("User not found. Try again");
           return null;
```